# How to get the number of buyers on each main channel based on the number of buyers on each sub-channel

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help to make the mysql query to get the number of buyers on each **main channel** based on the number of buyers on each **sub-channel**

Basically I have two tables, namely **tbl_channel** and **tbl_buyer** as below:

[image]

**Conditions:**

1. I just show number of buyers every **Master Channel** (parentid = 0) based on the number of buyers on each **sub-channel**
2. Every **buyer** in a channel_id (TBL_BUYER) with same **buyer_id** will count as one buyer

**The results I want:**

[image]

So far I just can only make a query to display the number of buyers at a sub-channel only, like this below:

```
SELECT count(aa.buyer_id) as Number_of_buyers FROM (SELECT b.buyer_id
FROM tbl_channel a 
RIGHT JOIN tbl_buyer b on (a.id=b.channel_id)
WHERE a.parentid_channel_id = 2 /* PARENT ID */
GROUP by b.buyer_id ORDER BY b.channel_id) aa
```

Can you help me make a complete query to produce results as shown above? Thank you before :)

Comment: why is `1` has value of `3` for *number of buyers*?

Comment: The data in tbl_buyer doesn't show anything about channel id 1, and your result has channel id 1 with 3 buyers. I think that's a bit confusing.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the Master 1st count from 3 to 5, but if you had other fix in mind, please feel free to override my change.

Comment: All: I think @JohnWoo has given me a solution that I want. Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.channel_id `Channel ID`,
        a.channel_title `Channel Title`,
        COUNT(DISTINCT c.buyer_id) `Number of Buyers`
FROM    tbl_Channel a
        INNER JOIN tbl_Channel b
            ON a.channel_ID = b.parent_channel_id
        INNER JOIN tbl_buyer c
            ON  b.channel_ID =  c.channel_ID
WHERE   a.parent_channel_id = 0
GROUP BY a.channel_id,
         a.channel_title
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efd00/1)